# Search is not returning expected results

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to connect to elasticsearch and do some basic query in 6.3.2 version.

The code I am trying is this:

```
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 30100, "http")));

SearchRequest sr = new SearchRequest(INDEX);
sr.indicesOptions(IndicesOptions.lenientExpandOpen());

SearchSourceBuilder ssb = new SearchSourceBuilder();
sr.source(ssb);

MatchQueryBuilder builder = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("logLevel.keyword", "ERROR");
    QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(builder);
    ssb.query(qb);

SearchResponse response = null;

try {
    response = client.search(sr);
    System.out.println("total hits ::: " + response.getHits().getTotalHits());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        client.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

System.out.println(response);
```

**UPDATE**
As suggested i am using the query only now. I tried the build query from APIs and i see the result but for some reason `response.getHits().getTotalHits()` is returning zero. The generated query looks like below and is giving me the expected result in kibana i.e. a total count of 1 :

```
GET /_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "logLevel.keyword": {
              "query": "ERROR",
              "operator": "OR",
              "prefix_length": 0,
              "max_expansions": 50,
              "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
              "lenient": false,
              "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
              "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Am missing some configuration for the restclient ?

Comment: if you just want the count of docs without grouping on any field, you could simply run a query with the required filters? I don't see why you need aggregations for that.
Date range can also be specified in the query itself, unless you want your counts grouped by specific date intervals

Comment: oh! ok am new to this API, can you please provide a sample? or can you point me to some reference examples for query itself as you have told ? The problem is there is lot of confusion in me wrt old and new APIs

Comment: check this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html
you need to build a query where you use term filter on `log_level` and range filter on the date field. set the size of the results to 0 since you just want the count. That optimises the query too i think.

Comment: changed the code that I am using now and updated in the code, I see 0 hits ideally I should get 1

Comment: You need to post the index mapping as well. `curl -XGET localhost:9200/index_name/_mappings?pretty=true`

Comment: how can I do that, can you post a complete example please ... I am having difficulty in making up the query correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178907/discussion-between-archit-saxena-and-raghuveer).

Comment: Anybody can you please suggest ?

Comment: In your mappings, i don't see the field LogLevel that you are trying to search on. If it is of type: keyword, it will perform case sensitive search when you try to search for "ERROR". Just a simple query like this should work:
GET index/_search
{
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "logLevel": "ERROR"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "date"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}. Try lowercasing ERROR if it doesn't.

Comment: Firstly I see the `logLevel` in the JSON I have shared. Secondly if this query is not working then why is it working in the kibana dev-tools ? I am feeling there is nothing wrong in query, something to do with the code... do you see ?

Comment: oh, my bad. I didn't expand the full text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you need all the parts in the query that you posted (like max_expansions etc). A simple query like below, should do the job if you only need the count of documents that match the criteria.

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/index_name/_search" -d'
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "logLevel": "ERROR"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "enter_date_here"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

Comment: To start with the DSL what you have put is not what am looking for. Importantly the generated DSL works perfectly fine but my code is returning 0 hits. I am sure am missing something. Should I create a saperate index for searching or something, am totally lost.

Comment: you need to update your question i think. What is it that you want to achieve? from what i could gather before you changed the question, you wanted to find the count of documents which have loglevel: error within some date range. Let me know if i'm wrong

Comment: That's correct, but see the caption as well, am not able to fetch the correct number of records that I should be getting. For any request I am getting zero. Since the `TransportClient` is going to be deprecated am planning to use the rest client. Its correct, the way I was querying was wrong which I have fixed, but the output has not changed.

Comment: can you paste the response that you are getting and the document in elasticsearch that should match your criteria?

Comment: I have added the complete information in the chat ... thanks

Comment: Hey, i went through the logs. It looks more like some error with the java client that you are using to query elasticsearch. I have no experience with Java, so i'm sorry i can't help you there. Perhaps you should post a new question with the error logs. The query is obviously working, but the client isn't.

Comment: But thanks for pointing me to the query part. Its true that I am trying to query the error logs only. So the JSON you see is the output that I expect.

Comment: oh golly. I assumed you pasted the entire error trace. I blame the chat UX.

Comment: I went through the java client documentation as well. Doesn't look like there's a problem there either. I hope you've already rechecked that you actually are querying the same elasticsearch index from kibana and your application.

Comment: you are absolutely right, I had a wrong index being queried from my rest client. thanks a lot.